# SQL query to either find record with accepted state OR maximum amount (if no accepted state) in a group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table for offers(id, amount, state, address_id) which joins to addresses(id, latitude, longitude).

*state is integer field - inspection: 0, pricing: 1, sent: 2, accepted: 3

Latitude and longitude are not unique validated. All the offers have 1 address.

Now, I have to find all the records which are either accepted OR has highest amount in a particular [longitude, latitude] group.

I have written separate queries for both, but unable to form a single query with the information.

Query to find highest amount in a group:

```
SELECT  distinct offers.id 
FROM "offers" 
  INNER JOIN "addresses" ON "addresses"."id" = "offers"."address_id" 
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT a.longitude, a.latitude, MAX(amount) AS total 
     FROM offers 
      INNER JOIN addresses a ON a.id = offers.address_id 
     WHERE state != 3 
     GROUP BY a.longitude, a.latitude
  ) AS sorted_offers ON sorted_offers.longitude = addresses.longitude 
                    AND sorted_offers.latitude = addresses.latitude 
                    AND sorted_offers.total = offers.amount
```

Comment: I have to find all the records which are either accepted OR has highest amount in a particular [longitude, latitude] group. >>> You want: either state=accepted distinct offerid or (not accepted distinct offerid that is group by longitude, latitude)?

Comment: @jian in [longitude, latitude] group, selected record must either be accepted or has highest amount.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/wK8x_KuN can you try this one.